# stacking rows as columns in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to stack rows of data into columns so that the variables in another column will repeat. I would like to turn something like this

```
tib <- tribble(~x, ~y, ~z, "a", 1,2, "b", 3,4)
> tib
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     2
2 b         3     4
```

into

```
t <- tribble(~X, ~Y, "a", 1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "b", 4)
> t
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  X         Y
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 b         3
4 b         4
```

Thanks for your help and sorry if I've missed this solution somewhere. I did a search, and tried applying gather(), spread(), but couldn't get it to work out.

Comment: What are the names of the columns?

Comment: You are looking for gather command https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/gather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `data.table::melt()`:

```
# Assuming your data is a data.frame
xyz <- data.frame(
  x = c("a", "b"),
  y = c(1, 3),
  z = c(2, 4)
)

library(data.table)
melt(xyz, id.vars = "x")[c(1, 3)]

  x value
1 a     1
2 b     3
3 a     2
4 b     4
```

Comment: great!.. thanks for the help.. also thanks to @akrun for the link

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with many packages. One possibility is `tidyr` and the function `gather` ([link](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html))

**EDIT**
Using  @sindri_baldur data:

```
library(tidyr)
xyz %>% 
  gather(class, measurement, -x)
```